# NGINX: redirect request_uri that contains http

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

I have rewritten all external links sent to standard output on the fly as an internal link in PHP from https://externalsite.com to https://myexamplesite.com/https://externalsite.com, yet I want Nginx to handle the request for this URL and not PHP.

I have tried it via the line below, but it is not working

`rewrite ^/http(.+)$  http$1 redirect;`

Please advise on the best way to redirect **https://myexamplesite.com/https://externalsite.com**, to **https://externalsite.com** on request

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort but it did not work due to not having https:// before the "$1"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have it work with this.

`rewrite ^/https?\W+(.*) https://$1 redirect;`

I am not sure why the former did not work but seems NGINX is passing it back internally.

NGINX seems not to honor an external redirect without the "https://" statically written before and jointly with the second option of the directive despite being captured in the parenthesis.